# Azure AKS execute command on cluster's nodes using ssh

Tags: linux, azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to patch nodes on Azure AKS cluster, the nodes running "Ubuntu 18.04 LTS", i need to install an update on those nodes, i got more than 20 clusters which each cluster has 8+ nodes.
i want to patch the nodes automatically using a script. to do that i need to execute commands on the nodes using ssh without login in.

I found a documentation for ssh "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh" but it does provide access to the node but not executing commands like regular ssh command:

```
ssh user@node "command"
```

i know that the default username for ssh to the nodes is azureusr, tried to ssh to the nodes using the internal ip and the azureusr but it timeout's after 2 minutes.

Please is there a way to do that ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What does "patch" mean in your context?

Comment: There is an exploit in those nodes and i need to install an update. all i need is to execute the commands for downloading and installing from outside the node using ssh (or whatever method you suggest)

Comment: Have you tried following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/node-updates-kured? If you are manually installing stuff I doubt its persistence after a PUT operation on the node pool. I would recommend using a privileged nsenter container Daemonset to make changes on all the nodes. If you want to use the `ssh user@node "command"` format after all, you can check out https://achrafbenalaya.com/2021/05/11/how-to-ssh-into-aks-nodes/ which details the AKS Node SSH guidelines that were documented by Microsoft before `kubectl debug` was introduced.